# How can I connect Amazon in Odoo?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, relation, odoo-15

Hi developers I have a problem, I have tried to sycronize Amazon with Odoo but when I link an Amazon account I mark this error

"An error was encountered while synchronizing Amazon orders. ForbiddenRequestBlocked: Developer is blocked from making calls for the MWS section Orders as part of MWS Deprecation process"

How can I solve this problem?

I tried to check it but I couldn't solve it.

[image]